# how view "et al" in the latex references

Tags: bibliographies

Hellow

I used this source to view the bibliographie

```
\usepackage{harvard}
.....
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{These}
```

i search how view a refence as `(Schilit et al, 1994). i used this declaration :

```
@article{Abc_2001,
    Author = {Anind K. Dey and Gregory D. Abowd and Salber Daniel},
    Title = {A Conceptual Framework and a Toolkit for Supporting the Rapid Prototyping of Context-aware Applications},
    Journal = {Hum.-Comput. Interact.},
    Volume = {16},
    Number = {2},
    Year = {2001},
    Pages = {97--166},
}



@article{Dey_2001,
    Author = {Bill Schilit and Norman Adams and Roy Want},
    Title = {Context-Aware Computing Applications},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1994 First Workshop on Mobile Computing Systems and Applications},
    Year = {1994},
    Pages = {85--90},
    Numpages = {6},
    Publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
    Address = {Washington, DC, USA},
}
```

`

[image: But the result is :]

I search how view all references as the second one (see Figure).

Thank you

Comment: your question is very unclear. What do you mean by view here?  Do you want to change the way latex formats those two references? The question would be a lot clearer if you provided a complete small document that used that bib file and produced the image shown.

Comment: i search how view the references in my document with "et al" as (Schilit et al, 1994). But using the package harvard the refenrences are cited differently once with "et al" and again include all author names. I want all the references as   (Schilit et al, 1994) without citing the names of all authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to your preamble the command `\citationmode{abbr}`

here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{harvard}
\citationmode{abbr}
\begin{document}
\cite{Abc_2001} and \cite{Dey_2001} ....
.....
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{These}
\end{document}
```

with

```
@article{Abc_2001,
    Author = {Anind K. Dey and Gregory D. Abowd and Salber Daniel},
    Title = {A Conceptual Framework and a Toolkit for Supporting the Rapid Prototyping of Context-aware Applications},
    Journal = {Hum.-Comput. Interact.},
    Volume = {16},
    Number = {2},
    Year = {2001},
    Pages = {97--166},
}



@article{Dey_2001,
    Author = {Bill Schilit and Norman Adams and Roy Want},
    Title = {Context-Aware Computing Applications},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1994 First Workshop on Mobile Computing Systems and Applications},
    Year = {1994},
    Pages = {85--90},
    Numpages = {6},
    Publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
    Address = {Washington, DC, USA},
}
```

and it gives: 
[image]